# Course Header Navigation in Moodle

Tags: javascript, php, html, moodle, mustache

I have a Moodle site. on site I have edumy theme but at particular course/view.php page have alpha theme I need edumy theme only on header of course on course/view.php

I try to modified theme templates to get edumy theme header on alpha theme page

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to set the theme for a course?

If so, go to Site admin > Appearance > Themes > Theme settings >

Allow course themes (allowcoursethemes)

Save changes

Then edit the settings for a course > Appearance > Force theme > Choose theme